# Image Size Properties Not Working in CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My question is a pretty straightforward one. I'm using Bootstrap 4.0 to make a website. I have a Carousel Element below which my Container begins. The Container consists of two Rows, one for the Footer and the other for the Columns that house my content. I'm trying to align the three columns side-by-side (like actual columns). Each Column consists of one DIV Element (Bootstrap Column Class); with one image and text below it image. This works fine when I set the size properties of the images in the index.html file. However, once I copy the same information into my custom CSS file, the columns become stacked. I'm pretty sure I'm calling the images with the correct Syntax in CSS. But its just not working. I'm attaching screenshots to give an idea of what I intent to do and what actually is happening.

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

HTML CODE:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <!-- Required meta tags -->

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href="custom.css">

    <title>AlphaGamigLeague</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <nav class="navbar nav-pills">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

                <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1G0450PwU5dcfQ9g4lRuZjl6C8MP8ZNbh" width="100px" height="100px">

            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

            </button>


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                 <li class="nav-item">

                     <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>

                </li>

                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">

                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">

                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>

                </form>

            </div>

        </nav>

        <!-- End Of Navigation Bar -->

        <!-- Beginning Of Carousel -->

        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


            <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>

                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>

            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="carousel-item active">

                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1G0450PwU5dcfQ9g4lRuZjl6C8MP8ZNbh" height="650px" width="400px" alt="First slide">

                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">

                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Rq95g-w1Dpr-pq9vuI4p9bVV2hHPHiIw" alt="Second slide">

                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">

                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1G0450PwU5dcfQ9g4lRuZjl6C8MP8ZNbh" alt="Third slide">

                </div>

            </div>

            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">

                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>

            </a>

            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">

                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>

            </a>

        </div>

        <!-- End Of Carousel -->

        <!-- Beginning Of Container -->

        <br>

        <br>

        <!-- Beginning Of Main Content -->

        <!-- Bootstrap Container Begins Here -->

        <div class="container">

            <!-- First Row Begins Here -->

            <div id = "myRow1" class="row">

                <!-- First Column Begins Here -->

                <div id = "whoarewe" class="col-md">

                    <br>

                    <h3>

                        Who Are We?

                    </h3>

                    <br>



                        <img id = "myfirstImage" src= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1TXd3BvbLa9kFb4N9bq4P8KY_cDx1flSF"class= "hover" width = "350px" height= "400px">

                        <p class= "fsfwt48t948489tugjwj4h9u4 ubuw ughwu9 g">


                        </p>

                    <br>

                    <p>

                    Alpha Gaming League, also known as AGL eSports, is a professional eSports organization. We aim to not only provide a platform for Pakistani gaming and eSports enthusiants to showcase their talent but also benefit in numerous ways; especially financially. Our goal is to be the very best in the business. We don't just want to be known as one of the key pioneers of the eSports industry in the country but want ot be known as the pioneers of the eSports industry that continue to raise the bar and set new standards in terms of eSports in Pakistan. The be the ultimate leader and lead by example is what AGL eSports thrives to be.

                    </p>


                </div>

                <!-- First Column Begins Here -->

                <!-- Second Column Begins Here -->


                <div id = "myRow1Column2" class="col-md">

                    <br>

                    <h3>

                        Our Tournaments 

                    </h3>

                    <br>



                        <img id = "mysecondImage" src= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1apY_1ssrqv9u1SRCiQoZOJG4DoFho87H" width = "350px" height= "400px">     



                    <br>

                    <p>

                    Alpha Gaming League(AGL eSports) holds a variety of tournaments every year. We are able to successfully do this based on years of knowledge and experience in the field. Some of the titles for which competitions and tournaments are held include:

                        <br>

                        <br>

                        Battlefield (Console + PC)
                        <br>
                        Blur (Console)
                        <br>
                        Call Of Duty (Console + PC)
                        <br>
                        Counter Strike(PC)
                        <br>
                        DoTA2 (PC)
                        <br>
                        FIFA (Console)
                        <br>
                        Fortnite (Consile + PC)
                        <br>
                        Player Unknown's Battle Grounds (Console + PC)
                        <br>
                        Tekken (Console)
                        <br>
                        etc...
                        <br>
                        <br>

                        These titles are just a few of the many we have to offer.

                        Not only this, but players at our competitions are guaranteed to win exciting prozes, which includes prize money, goodi bags and much more.

                    </p>


                </div>

                <!-- Second Column Ends Here -->

                <!-- Third Column Begins Here -->

                <div id = "myRow1Column3" class="col-md">

                    <br>

                    <h3>

                        Partnerships

                    </h3>

                    <br>



                        <img id ="mythirdImage" src= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1X0J3m9a8V5gOVu5WX1VwBQMMPWar4H7q" width = "350px" height= "400px">     



                    <br>

                    <p>

                        At alpha Gaming League, we believe in the power of unity and working together as a team. It is only by working together that positive results can be achieved. We are always on the lookout for individuals or groups of individuals that have something exiting and unique to bring to the table. Because let's face it, in today's world, only unique ideas survive. If you or your organization thinks it has what it takes to fulfill our expectations and is interested in working alongside us, don't hesitate to get in touch with us. You can "Click Here" to send us a query and get in-touch with us. 

                    </p>


                </div>

                <!-- Third Column Ends Here -->

            </div>

            <!-- First Row Ends Here -->

            <!-- Footer Begins Here -->

            <!-- Second Row Begins Here -->

            <div id = "myRow2" class="row">

                <!-- First Column Begins Here -->

                <div id = "myRow2Column1" class="col-md">

                    sdasdasdasdasdasda

                    <br>

                    <!-- Disclaimer DIV Begins Here -->

                    <div id = "disclaimer">

                    <p>

                        All rights reserved. No fhsofsei fhioyw39847 ryo8wrt 48wotr o3qwryy 9aw4ro87

                        </p>

                    </div>

                   <!-- Disclaimer DIV Ends Here --> 

                </div>

                <!-- First Column Ends Here -->

                <!-- Second Columns Begins Here -->

                <div id = "myRow2Column2" class="col-md">

                    <br>

                    <!-- Instagram Icon DIV Begins Here -->

                    <div id = "instagram">

                        <img src= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1jiCKayOmqF5hk1FDrF9wAfiG2VYlHoki" width= "50px" height = "50px" align = "right">

                    </div>

                    <!-- Instagram Icon DIV Ends Here -->

                    <!-- Twitter Icon DIV Beginss Here -->

                    <div id = "twitter">

                        <img src= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1JhT0U6SXfrZ8jyKOUhbZoEs7kpQ7bdXp" height= "50px" width= "50px" align = "right">

                    </div>

                    <!-- Twitter Icon DIV Ends Here -->

                    <!-- Facebook Icon DIV Begins Here -->

                    <div id = "facebook">

                    <img src= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ZGjOfBJHrzCrXeP3hoc2FsgCLFX41sq2" height= "50px" width= "50px" align = "right">

                    </div>

                    <!-- Facebook Icon DIV Ends Here -->

                 </div>

                <!-- Second Column Ends Here -->

            </div>

            <!-- Second Row Ends Here -->

        </div>

        <!-- Bootstrap Container Ends Here -->

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.logo_image {

    height: 200px;

    width: 100px;

}

/* .nav-brand allows the logo properties to be changed */

.navbar-brand {


}

.navbar{

    background-color: black;    

}

.navbar-toggler{

    background-color: orange;

    border-radius: 8px;

}

.navbar navbar-expand-lg{

   background-color: aqua; 

}

.collapse{

    background-color: aqua;

}

.btn{

    background-color: whitesmoke;

}

.body{

    background-color: black:

}

.carousel-inner{

    height: 650px;

}

.carousel-item active{

    height: 90px;

}

.item active{

    height: 50px;

}

#myRow1{

    background-color: pink;

    height:auto;

    width: auto;

}

#whoarewe{

    text-align: center;

    height: auto;

    font-family: monospace;

    font-weight: 900;

    font-size: 15px;

}

#myRow1Column2{

    text-align: center;

    height: auto;

    font-family: monospace;

    font-weight: 900;

    font-size: 15px;

}

#myRow2{

    background-color: forestgreen;

    height:auto;

}

#myRow1Column3{

    text-align: center;

    height: auto;

    font-family: monospace;

    font-weight: 900;

    font-size: 15px;

}

#disclaimer{

    width: 300px;

    text-align: left;

}

#socialMediaLinks{

    position: relative;

    bottom:  30px;

}

#myRow2Column2{

    margin-right: 40px;

    margin-left: 100px;

}

#instagram{

    position: relative;

    right: 20px;

}

#twitter{

    position: relative;

    right: 40px;

}

#facebook{

    position: relative;

    right: 60px;

}

#myfirstImage{

    width = 150px;

    height= 400px;

}

#mysecondImage{


    width = 350px;

    height= 400px;

}

#mythirdImage{

    width = 350px;

    height= 400px;

}

#firstImage{



}

#secondImage{



}

#thirdImage{



}


#secondImage:hover{

    opacity: 0.6;

    visibility: visible;

}
```

[Intended Layout. Works when image size dimensions are specified in index.html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc86m.jpg)

[Actual layout. When image size dimensions are removed from index.html and added to the CSS file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNBlA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove fix width from the images and add the `img-fluid` class to them.

I mean, what exactly do you expect to happen when you set fix width on the images? Anyway, the first step is to remove the fix width and then, to make the images responsive, you add the `img-fluid` class.

Here's the working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap Container Begins Here -->

<div class="container">

    <!-- First Row Begins Here -->

    <div id = "myRow1" class="row">

        <!-- First Column Begins Here -->

        <div id = "whoarewe" class="col-md">

            <br>

            <h3>

                Who Are We?

            </h3>

            <br>



            <img class="img-fluid" id = "myfirstImage" src= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1TXd3BvbLa9kFb4N9bq4P8KY_cDx1flSF"class= "hover">

            <p class= "fsfwt48t948489tugjwj4h9u4 ubuw ughwu9 g">


            </p>

            <br>

            <p>

                Alpha Gaming League, also known as AGL eSports, is a professional eSports organization. We aim to not only provide a platform for Pakistani gaming and eSports enthusiants to showcase their talent but also benefit in numerous ways; especially financially. Our goal is to be the very best in the business. We don't just want to be known as one of the key pioneers of the eSports industry in the country but want ot be known as the pioneers of the eSports industry that continue to raise the bar and set new standards in terms of eSports in Pakistan. The be the ultimate leader and lead by example is what AGL eSports thrives to be.

            </p>


        </div>

        <!-- First Column Begins Here -->

        <!-- Second Column Begins Here -->


        <div id = "myRow1Column2" class="col-md">

            <br>

            <h3>

                Our Tournaments 

            </h3>

            <br>



            <img class="img-fluid" id = "mysecondImage" src= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1apY_1ssrqv9u1SRCiQoZOJG4DoFho87H">     



            <br>

            <p>

                Alpha Gaming League(AGL eSports) holds a variety of tournaments every year. We are able to successfully do this based on years of knowledge and experience in the field. Some of the titles for which competitions and tournaments are held include:

                <br>

                <br>

                Battlefield (Console + PC)
                <br>
                Blur (Console)
                <br>
                Call Of Duty (Console + PC)
                <br>
                Counter Strike(PC)
                <br>
                DoTA2 (PC)
                <br>
                FIFA (Console)
                <br>
                Fortnite (Consile + PC)
                <br>
                Player Unknown's Battle Grounds (Console + PC)
                <br>
                Tekken (Console)
                <br>
                etc...
                <br>
                <br>

                These titles are just a few of the many we have to offer.

                Not only this, but players at our competitions are guaranteed to win exciting prozes, which includes prize money, goodi bags and much more.

            </p>


        </div>

        <!-- Second Column Ends Here -->

        <!-- Third Column Begins Here -->

        <div id = "myRow1Column3" class="col-md">

            <br>

            <h3>

                Partnerships

            </h3>

            <br>



            <img class="img-fluid" id ="mythirdImage" src= "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1X0J3m9a8V5gOVu5WX1VwBQMMPWar4H7q">     



            <br>

            <p>

                At alpha Gaming League, we believe in the power of unity and working together as a team. It is only by working together that positive results can be achieved. We are always on the lookout for individuals or groups of individuals that have something exiting and unique to bring to the table. Because let's face it, in today's world, only unique ideas survive. If you or your organization thinks it has what it takes to fulfill our expectations and is interested in working alongside us, don't hesitate to get in touch with us. You can "Click Here" to send us a query and get in-touch with us. 

            </p>


        </div>

        <!-- Third Column Ends Here -->

    </div>

    <!-- First Row Ends Here -->

</div>
```

Comment: Hi.

That worked! Thank you very much! I totally missed the img-fluid class.